# Drawing with threads on a PictureBox Image

Tags: c#, multithreading, gdi

I'm trying to draw multiple ellipses on an Image from the PictureBox with a thread, but when I interact with the form (like move it), then GDI throws an InvalidOperationException (object currently in use) as I clone the current Image in the thread.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to animate a few shapes on the canvas, and allow the user to have a smooth experience while interacting with the form (as well as zooming in on the image etc).

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a separate image that your background thread interacts with, and then clone it to your UI thread when there's something new to show.  The cloning should be done via a BeginInvoke

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call BeginInvoke to get on the GUI thread before interacting with the PictureBox.

Like so...

```
form.BeginInvoke(ManipulatePictureBox);
```